# Change href in HTML tag does not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have this HTML tag:

```
<a href="show_comments.php?id=6">(show comments)</a>
```

I would like to change its href. I am triying with jquery but It does not works:

```
$('a[href="show_comments.php?id=6"]').attr('href', 'xyz.php');
```

I also tried with querySelectorAll:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[href='show_comments.php?id=6']").setAttrtibute('href','xyz.php');
```

**UPDATE:**

It was a timing problem. Using $( document ).ready(function() {}); both solutions works.

Why these solutions don't work? I would like to do it without jQuery but any solution is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly isn't working here?

Comment: I've got the solution. Main problem was that the script tag executed before the page was loaded. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**
It was a timing problem. Using `$( document ).ready(function() {});` both solutions work.

The issue was that it is a CSRF attack, so html have to be loaded to attack successfully (the tag I wanted to change was loaded after the JS script).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an id to this element and then selecting this id in jQuery or by play JS

Let's assume that the  tag has an id called changeUrl

```
$("#changeUrl").attr('href', 'xyz.php');
```

or

```
document.querySelector("#changeUrl").setAttrtibute('href','xyz.php');
```

Comment: `.changeUrl` is a class, not an id. You can make it an id if you want, but your example code is not using an id. Also, it would be helpful to provide the updated HTML code with added the id/class.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do it individually on every node when you're using `querySelectorAll` because it returns you a NodeList which doesn't have `setAttribute` method. Only nodes have that method:

```
document.querySelectorAll("a[href='show_comments.php?id=6']").forEach(node => node.setAttrtibute('href','xyz.php'))
```

EDIT: If you have just a single node, use `document.querySelector`

```
document.querySelector("a[href='show_comments.php?id=6']").setAttrtibute('href','xyz.php')
```

Load your JS just before `</body>` to ensure JS has access to complete DOM

Comment: That's not true of the jQuery case though

Comment: Thanks you very much!! It helps a lot. I also use $( document ).ready(function()}); to execute it after page loads. Thanks:)

Comment: @charlietfl yeah I missed that detail. But the OP answered that he was loading script before, so its fine now